# How do i make my code not return formulas with locked cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code to print some formulas into my sheet, but when I run the code it prints the formulas with locked cells. However, I need the cells unlocked as I will auto fill the remaining rows with the same formulas. Can anyone help me?

Code:

(...)

```
Set ProdRange = Range(Cells(2,3), Cells(2, lCol-1))

Cells(2, lCol).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & ProdRange.Address & ")"
```

(...)

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Do you mean that after running the above two code lines, the cells receiving the formula becomes locked? Are you sure they are not locked before? Anyhow, the locking is functional only if the worksheet is protected. Do you show us only  a part of your code, and there is an `Unprotect` sheet line before it, followed by `Protect`?

Comment: I meant locked as in the code becomes: "=AVERAGE($C$2:$F$2)". I dont have any part of my code with Protect or Unprotect...

Comment: This is not locked! It is an absolute reference.Try using `ProdRange.Address(0, 0)` to have relative reference...

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution is to delete `$` from the string.

```
Set ProdRange = Range(Cells(2,3), Cells(2, lCol-1))

Cells(2, lCol).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & Replace(ProdRange.Address, "$", "") & ")"
```

Comment: `ProdRange.Address(0, 0)` will return the relative reference...